# How to compare a string as an integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

In **SQL Server 2012**, I have a set of columns that are defined as `VARCHAR`. The values are thresholds for a metric and can be either numbers or string values. For example, the thresholds for temperature are numbers `0` and `100`, whereas, thresholds for door would be `open` and `closed`.

I want to test a value `[ResponseValue]` to see if it's in between two define threshold values, `[Value_Threshold_min]` and `[Value_Threshold_max]`. The `[ResponseValue]` can be either `NUMERIC` or `VARCHAR` but always stored as `VARCHAR`. The `Threshold_max/min` are stored as `VARCHAR`.

```
SELECT responsevalue 
        , (CASE WHEN ResponseValue BETWEEN steps.value_threshold_min AND steps.Value_Threshold_max else END THEN column_color 
FROM steps 
JOIN responses on responses.stepid = steps.id 
WHERE stepid = 4447
```

This does not properly test values that are numeric. For example, 12 is said to be in between 100 and 200 because it's being evaluated as a string.

I've tried to check if the value is numeric and if so, cast it to int but this fails whenever the value is alpha numeric.

```
CASE WHEN isnumeric([Responses].[ResponseValue]) = 1 
THEN CAST([Responses].[ResponseValue] as int) 
ELSE [Responses].[ResponseValue] END) 
BETWEEN steps.value_threshold_min AND steps.Value_Threshold_max THEN column _color
```

How can I treat a number as a number and string as a string when comparing?

Comment: what version of sql, 2008, 2012, etc

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: Then definitely use `TRY_CONVERT()` instead of `ISNUMERIC`. `ISNUMERIC` can lead to false positives for this... i.e. try `SELECT ISNUMERIC('1e4')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on 2012, you can use [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

> Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds;
>   otherwise, returns null.

```
SELECT responsevalue,
    CASE 
        WHEN TRY_CONVERT(INT,ResponseValue) BETWEEN TRY_CONVERT(INT,steps.value_threshold_min) AND TRY_CONVERT(INT,steps.Value_Threshold_max) THEN 'Int Color'
        WHEN ResponseValue BETWEEN steps.value_threshold_min AND steps.Value_Threshold_max THEN 'VarcharColor'
        ELSE NULL
    END as column_color 
FROM steps 
JOIN responses on responses.stepid = steps.id 
WHERE stepid = 4447
```

Comment: No worries @DavidWinslow

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you *know* the values are valid digits, you can just convert them:

```
SELECT responsevalue,
        (CASE WHEN r.ResponseValue BETWEEN convert(int, s.value_threshold_min) AND convert(int, s.Value_Threshold_max)
              ELSE . . .
         END) column_color 
FROM steps s JOIN
     responses r
     on r.stepid = s.id 
WHERE stepid = 4447;
```

This can cause a problem, if some values are strings and some ints -- and this can even occur in rows not being select by the query.  If this is an issue, then in SQL Server 2012+, you can use `try_convert()`:

```
SELECT responsevalue,
        (CASE WHEN r.ResponseValue BETWEEN try_convert(int, s.value_threshold_min) AND try_convert(int, s.Value_Threshold_max)
              ELSE . . .
         END) column_color 
FROM steps s JOIN
     responses r
     on r.stepid = s.id 
WHERE stepid = 4447;
```

Comment: I get the same error as I do with isnumeric. Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Yes' to data type int. [SQL State=S0001, DB Errorcode=245]. The values in responseValue can be numbers or strings. When they are numbers, I need to treat them as numbers for the "between" function to work. I can't treat everything like numbers because some of the values are strings.

Comment: @DavidWinslow . . . Did you then use `try_convert()` as I recommended?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I think it's on the responsevalue column but could be wrong