# SQL AND Operator returns wrong value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am using the following query:

Getting all records:

```
SELECT ykey2 AS tblLower,
       ykey3 AS tblUpper,
       i1 AS tblResult 
FROM customTableItems 
WHERE fk_customTable = 189
```

After applying filter to this query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST((REPLACE(ykey2, ',', '.')) AS DECIMAL(18, 9)) AS tblLower,
    CAST((REPLACE(ykey3, ',', '.')) AS DECIMAL(18, 9)) AS tblUpper,
    i1 AS tblResult 
FROM 
    customTableItems 
WHERE
    fk_customTable = 189
    AND (ykey2 < '3') AND (ykey3 >= '3')
```

and output of these two queries are:

[image]

I am expecting only one row as per my filter but it is returning always 2 rows as you can see in second snapshot.

I am using conversion in select before getting, but didn't get any success.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause (which is logically processed before `SELECT`) is doing a string comparison, not a numerical one. Why is the data being stored with an inappropriate data type in the first place?

Comment: Actually logic was created in application to save records with comma separated but now we are using these records as decimal.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734266/how-to-compare-a-string-as-an-integer

Comment: `'3'` is a string, so the DBMS is probably using a string compare, where '1000' is alphabetically *less* than '3'

Answer (score 1):

its refer to minus ASCII is less than the number you can use this

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
CAST((REPLACE(ykey2, ',', '.')) AS DECIMAL(18, 9)) AS tblLower,
CAST((REPLACE(ykey3, ',', '.')) AS DECIMAL(18, 9)) AS tblUpper,
i1 AS tblResult 
FROM 
customTableItems 
WHERE
fk_customTable = 189)A
WHERE (tblLower < 3) AND (tblUpper >= 3)
```

Comment: fix ur typo in the where condition

Comment: @RAHULSR No typo there AFAICT; just poor (or rather, no) indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
    CAST((REPLACE(ykey2, ',', '.')) AS DECIMAL(18, 9)) AS tblLower,
    CAST((REPLACE(ykey3, ',', '.')) AS DECIMAL(18, 9)) AS tblUpper,
    i1 AS tblResult 
FROM 
    customTableItems 
WHERE
    fk_customTable = 189) a WHERE a.tblLower < 3 AND a.tblUpper >=3
```

Comment: This gives a syntax error; please give the subquery an alias.